# How to create a clickable button that is disabled until clicking a checkbox, that also reveals text when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a button that reveals text when clicked. But I also need a terms and conditions checkbox that disables the button until checked. Once the checkbox and button have both been clicked it would reveal the text.
Here's what I have so far, but without the checkbox:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "1976";
}
```

```html
<p>I Agree to the Terms & Conditions</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">View Lockbox Code</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you just need to change button `disabled` attribute every time your checkbox is changed:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('view');

function toggleButton() {
  button.disabled = !button.disabled;
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "1976";
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="terms" onChange="toggleButton()">
<label for="terms"> I Agree to the Terms & Conditions </label>
<button id="view" onclick="myFunction()" disabled>View Lockbox Code</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Here I added `toggleButton()` function which changes your button `disabled` attribute to the opposite value.

Comment: Ortophius, thank you so much. This code does exactly what I want when I test it. But for some reason, when I put the code on my website, it won't display the innerhtml after checking the box and clicking the button. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Anything wrong with this logic?

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("test").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector('label[for="test"]').style.display = "block";

}

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "1976";
}
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none
}

label[for="test"] {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">View Lockbox Code</button>

<label for="test">I Agree to the Terms & Conditions</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" value="test" onclick="myFunction2()">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

OR:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "1976";
}

function myFunction2(event) {
  let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  event.target.checked ? btn.disabled = false : btn.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()" disabled>View Lockbox Code</button>

<br>
<label for="test">I Agree to the Terms & Conditions</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" value="test" onclick="myFunction2(event)">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if you check and then uncheck the checkbox, then press the button you will still be able to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name=check]');
btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    checkbox.checked
        ? (document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '1976')
        : alert('Please agree to Terms and conditions!');
});
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        btn.classList.remove('disabled');
    }
});
```

```css
.disabled {
    border: 1px solid #b4b1b1;
    background-color: #dddbdb;
    color: #6666;
}
```

```html
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="">
  <p>I Agree to the Terms & Conditions</p>
  <button id="btn" class="btn disabled">View Lockbox Code</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
```